# Classical potential and particle creation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, potential

I was reading up some references about QM/QFT and I came across this note (actually a problem set): [https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~yuvalg/p4444/hw8-sol.pdf](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/%7Eyuvalg/p4444/hw8-sol.pdf)

In question 1, the author mentioned that "In the limit where particle production and annihilation can be neglected, one can use the idea of potentials. In QFT, this can be used to find how a potential is generated from particle exchange. In particular, the statement that “the photon is the carrier of the electric force” can be understood."

Can someone please elaborate more about this? In particular, why can we use the notion of potentials if particle production and annihilation can be neglected and how is a potential generated from particle exchange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a complete discussion of Weinberg's "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics". In Chapters 7 and 8, he discusses how the non-relativistic, elastic scattering, that is neglecting creation and annihilation, can be described given a Hamiltonian $H=H_0+V(\bf{x})$ obtaining in the Born approximation (initial and final states as free particles) that the scattering amplitude depends on the potential as the expression in the notes $f(q)=\int d^3x \exp{iqx} V(x) $ with q = k-k' (transferred momentum). In the case of the creation and annihilation of particles, you may use the formalism of S-matrix $S_{\beta\alpha}$ representing the transition rate between the asymptotic initial ($\alpha$) and final ($\beta$) states. If you assume an elastic scattering generated by a particle exchange (let's say e+N->e+N, with photon exchange) you will find the propagator of the exchanged particle. The particle exchanged is a formal mathematical representation of a perturbative series. It is also virtual since it has $q^2\neq0$ (which is not the case for a real photon). Finally, for the general case with creation and annihilation, you will use a more general formalism (Scattering amplitude) which recovers the scattering on the potential in the case of non-relativistic elastic scattering.
Hope it could be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I briefly took a look at Weinberg's book and it seems to provide the standard QM scattering theory. Let me put my question in this way. Then why can't we use the notion of potentials when we have particle creation and annihilation? @Marellman

Comment: Actually, it is a matter of definition. The most satisfactory theory known is the QFT providing the fundamental concept of Field (each corresponding to a particle). In QFT no interaction occurs without the creation and annihilation (C&A) of particles, neither elastic scattering. The easiest answer to your question then is that the C&A of particles is an RQM fundamental concept while the potential is a classical description that must be recovered in the non-relativistic limit of RQM (see Peskin sec 4.8).

Comment: Technically you cannot use a classical description for non-classical phenomena. Hope to be a little bit clear.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I got that the concept of potential is classical and particle creation/annihilation is relativistic. But, can you please provide more intuitive way to see this? It is not clear to me that which aspect of potential makes it not well defined/not usable when particle creation/annihilation comes to a picture. @Lox

Comment: There is no a priori contradiction between C&A and potentials. If the scattering is elastic and non-relativistic you can compute the scattering amplitude in the Born approximation. In general, for the scattering over a potential V(r), you need to solve the general, non-trivial, Lippmann-Schwinger equation. In this case, things are much more complicated and the potential is no more the Fourier transform of the scattering amplitude (which can be computed with QFT C&A Feynman rules for example). My suggestion is to go through one complete QFT book such as Weinberg's, Peskin's, or Itzkinson's.